# Can an ActiveX Script (DTS) return complete instead of success or failure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, activex, dts

An ActiveX Script in a DTS package can return DTSTaskExecResult_Success or DTSTaskExecResult_Failure.  Is there a way to indicate that it is not a success without failing the entire package?  We'd like it to keep going, but in a different direction.  The options for a path are Success, Failure, and Completion, but it appears the only return values for the ActiveX Script are Failure and Success.  'DTSTaskExecResult_Completion' isn't right.  What is?

(The solution we're probably going to pursue is modifying this to SSIS, but I wanted to know if it was possible in DTS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the *DTSTaskExecResult_Retry* return value; it tells you that it failed, but doesn't failout completely?

Edit: sorry it is : *DTSTaskExecResult_RetryStep*

---

FYI: ActiveScriptTask objects have full access to the GlobalVariables collection, which provides a way to share information across tasks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when using the ActiveX DTS Component, your options are limited to Success/Failure.  :(

-Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the options are limited to Success/Failure.
You can also use RetryStep option, but to do what? This option just repeat the step and the DTS never end.
The option that I use, is to use Success result, always.
But previously to set the result, I do my checking, and if I don't want to execute the next step, just set the task (the next task) as Completed.
By this way, the next task is not executed and you succeed in your purpose.

Sample:

```
Set oPackage = DTSGlobalVariables.Parent
If HasRows = 0 Then
    oPackage.Steps("DTSStep_DTSExecuteSQLTask_1").ExecutionStatus = DTSStepExecStat_Completed
End If
Main = DTSTaskExecResult_Success
```

Hope this can help to anyone.

Regards,